# The invocation of the constructor on type that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception xamlparseexeption

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I wanted to add a JumpList to my Windows Phone app, so I downloaded bewise phone controls toolkit.
I have a main window and when I click an icon on my ApplicationBar which navigate me to a page with JumpList:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Lista.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

it throws an exception:

```
The invocation of the constructor on type 'Bewise.Phone.JumpList' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. [Line: 33 Position: 26]
```

Even if there's an empty page with only JumpList on it (and nothing done with it).

Comment: what is it in the place where exception pointing at (line 33 position 26)?

Comment: This exception usually comes with inner exception that is actually causing the failure and it's more relevant. Do you have inner exception? What is it?